# How Can I stream AAC format from http://ipaddress:port?

Tags: stream, jwplayer, aac, shoutcast

I am looking for a free flash player (not windows media player) to stream AAC audio from a website which has a link of this type: ipaddress:port, whith.
What player can I utilise?
I tried to use JWplayer, but I could not able to set it.

Comment: JW Player supports AAC.  Care to show us the code for what you attempted so we can suggest a fix?

Comment: I read on the JWplayer site that this player does not supports crossdomain. In fact, I need to put this player in a site called www.mysite.com and to call stream from ipaddress:port.
I don't found any example of this usage.

Answer (score 0):

Use the shoutcast player, as in the jwplayer example below or this one: http://www.wavestreaming.com/player/free-shoutcast-flash-player

Basically your source is an shoutcast stream, so you can use any flash based shoutcast audio player.

Comment: You definitely **do not** need RTMP to stream AAC.  In any case, he's already mentioned that the streams are available, and he just wants to play them.

Comment: You cant use flash to stream from the port directly, you need to transcode it or remux to RTMP first to feed the server and then remux to RTMP or to HTTP OSMF and play with standard jwplayer etc.

Comment: Do you have any sources for that?  I could have sworn I've done this in the past via SHOUTcast server-side, and JWPlayer on the front end.  http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/12539/supported-video-and-audio-formats

Comment: He, so this is the answer, use shoudcast, I'll edit mine one.

Comment: as I wrote before, JWplayer seems does not supports crossdomain.
My intention is to stream audio from h t t p: / / ipaddress:port address type. 
Please, can you post a simple example of this player type?

Comment: How I can utilise shoutcast? Are there official shoutcast flash player?
My stream hosting is yet on shoutcase.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use ViaStreaming services, they offer free for clients aac+, aac, mp3 stream flash player without any transcoder or additional server, direct from SHOUTcast server.

Example: http://s1.viastreaming.net/8100

Comment: I have yet a subscription with shoutcast.
Are there others solutions?